# How to implement worklight server side serverSessionTimeout?

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server, worklight-security

I am trying to implement serverSessionTimeout in worklight server. I enabled `serverSessionTimeout=5` and `sso.cleanup.taskFrequencyInSeconds=5` in worklight.properties but no luck. We have user db entry for each user login. Ideally it should remove the user db entry once the session reached 5 minutes, but I am not able do clean the user db entry from server side. I appreciate if anybody help me on this.

Comment: Please greatly elaborate on the scenario of your application. Specifically what is and where is the "user db entry". Another question: the server session timeout will occur only if there was app INACTIVITY for 5 minutes, is this what you are referring to?

Comment: Thanks for quick response. For every user successful log in we are inserting in to DB, this is external Oracle DB. Trying to implement server side session timeout if mobile app is closed forcefully or internet data failure, so we enabled serverSessionTimeout=5 and and sso.cleanup.taskFrequencyInSeconds=5. when server idle session reaches 5 minutes it should remove the db user entry.

Comment: Some followup questions: How do you simulate server idle session reaches 5 minutes? For example do you put the app in background? How do you make the server session timeout event delete the user from the external oracle database?

Comment: once the user login's we start the timer and for every next tap (touch) we restart the timer. once the app goes idle or background we forcefully logout, in logout we remove the db entry.

Comment: So what is the question, in fact? how to access your database and delete the user rows?

Comment: my question is when app is closed forcefully how to remove the user entry in DB? how to implement serverSessionTimeout? whatever i explained earlier is from client side is good. just wanted to know how to implement server side?

Comment: Are you using Worklight's own DB entry, or are you using your own?
Additionally, configuration of `serverSessionTimeout` instructs the application server to invalidate sessions after the specified amount of time, but the actual cleanup can occur at the application server's discretion and cannot be relied upon for time-critical scenarios.
`sso.cleanup.taskFrequencyInSeconds` is part of a different feature [http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fdevref%2Ft_configuring_device_SSO.html] that is unrelated to what you are trying to acheive

Comment: The answers for this question may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22019110/serversessiontimeout-not-working-ibm-worklight/24500156#24500156

Answer (score 0):

As Iddo mentioned in the comments:

1. `sso.cleanup.taskFrequencyInSeconds` is related to an entirely different feature
2. `serverSessionTimeout` instructs the application server to invalidate sessions after the specified amount of time, but the actual cleanup can occur at the application server's discretion ([see jaalger2's answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22019110/serversessiontimeout-not-working-ibm-worklight/)

So in order to control the session, you need to setup the values to your liking. After that, simply let the application sever handle the memory threads.

Is there any particular reason why after the above you also need to access the database and delete rows from it? This should be handled automatically, not "manually".